# Create a CSV from a SQL query using XSL

Tags: sql, csv, xslt, header

I need help to create a CSV file based on a SQL query.

This is how the current XSL looks like:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="iso-8859-1"/>
<xsl:param name="fieldNames" select="'yes'" />
<xsl:template match="NewDataSet">
    <xsl:text></xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Table"/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Table">
    <xsl:for-each select="*">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
            <xsl:value-of select="','"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
<xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Everything works fine, except the fact that I need to add a header row in the CSV with predefined values for each value. How can I do that?

This is how it looks now: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8otj.png)

This is how I want the CSV to look like: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPgst.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:text>foo,bar,baz
</xsl:text>
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

where `foo,bar,baz` would be your column names.

Comment: Hi Martin! Thanks a lot!